# How to update python version in linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, updates

How to update python(2.4) to python 2.6 in redhat linux terminal?

I tried `sudo apt-get install python2.6` but returned `sudo: apt-get: command not found`
,  I am new to linux, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: what linux disto do you use?

Comment: @Joseph: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are *off topic* here. There is a sister site about Linux administration.

The exact way of upgrading python depends on the particular Linux version that you have.

`apt-get` only works on Debian and Ubuntu Linux. On SuSE, you can try `yast`. Fedora has a package manager called `yum` I believe.

Details should be in the **documentation of your Linux distribution**.

Some Linux distributions may even have multiple python versions installed at the same time.

Try running `python2.6`, maybe it is already installed.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I managade to install python2.7, but `python -V` still shows python 2.4.3...?

Comment: Your default python the probably still is python 2.4 - this is not bad, as some application might *expect* it to be that way.
Try running `python2.7` if you want python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better install a new version of python in your own dir instead updating the default in the /usr/bin/

for example, you can download the source from official website, then compile and install it in your own dir such as /home/usrname/python. then edit the bashrc to add it to the  PATH.

Comment: I have multiple pythons ( in debian ) with names like /usr/bin/python2-6.

Comment: No, that is not a good idea. Because **you do not get automatic security updates anymore**. Stick to the distribution version.